# Cross-platform client/server RPC over TCP/IP with Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, rpc, remoting

I'm currently looking for a portable RPC framework for handling client/server communications on a local network.
The server will run on a Windows PC and the clients will be iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices.

It seems that System.Runtime.Remoting is not supported on iOS and that System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding (needed for WCF over TCP/IP) is not available in Xamarin.

I know that the lack of run-time code generation on iOS makes the generation of proxy classes impossible, it's why the solution will probably involve ahead-of-time code generation.

Are there any already existing solutions for doing RPC over TCP/IP with Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? (written for xamarin.forms)
https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Comment: It's interesting, unfortunately it doesn't include an RPC layer.